# Scrollviewer without background

Tags: wpf, background, scrollviewer

I would like to ask you if somebody know how to create ScrollViewer without background. I know that it is not possible with style or template (I guess) and must be created new component from ScrollVeiwer, but I can't find which method/property override.

For example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfScroll.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
  <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="bt"></Button>
    <ScrollViewer Background="{x:Null}" Margin="20">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{x:Null}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I want is ability to click on button "bt" on background between rectangles.

Thanks for advice.
-pav-

Comment: Well, i guess you know that you can set IsHitTestVisible="False" to the scrollviewer. The Problem is, that the scrollviewer swallows your mouse events.

Comment: Yes, I know, but as you said, mouse events will be gone and I need them.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste below style as it is :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
                Value="false" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="#ADABAB" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="7" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid x:Name="GridRoot"

                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                                CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Brown"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Height="Auto"
                                Margin="0,1,0,1"
                                Background="Transparent" />
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                IsDirectionReversed="true"
                                Focusable="false">
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarTrackThumb}" />
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp"
                                                Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                                Opacity="0"
                                                Focusable="false" />
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown"
                                                Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                                Opacity="0"
                                                Focusable="false" />
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                </Track>

                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                    Property="IsMouseOver"
                                    Value="true">
                                    <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}"
                                    TargetName="Thumb"
                                    Property="Background" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                    Property="IsDragging"
                                    Value="true">
                                    <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}"
                                    TargetName="Thumb"
                                    Property="Background" />
                                </Trigger>

                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                    Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Thumb"
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                                    Value="Horizontal">
                                    <Setter TargetName="GridRoot"
                                    Property="LayoutTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Track"
                                    Property="LayoutTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Width"
                                    Value="Auto" />
                                    <Setter Property="Height"
                                    Value="8" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Thumb"
                                    Property="Tag"
                                    Value="Horizontal" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="PageDown"
                                    Property="Command"
                                    Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="PageUp"
                                    Property="Command"
                                    Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ScrollBarTrackThumb"
            TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    Height="Auto"
                                    Fill="Transparent" />
                                <Border x:Name="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                                CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Yellow"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Height="Auto"
                                Margin="0,1,0,1"
                                Background="Transparent" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag"
                                    Value="Horizontal">
                                    <Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                                    Property="Width"
                                    Value="Auto" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                                    Property="Height"
                                    Value="6" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

[image: Transparent Scrollbar]

Comment: The question is something else. You can not click on button with name "bt" (which is behind scrollviewer) between rectangles, because ScrollViewer has transparent background (for events) and it can not be changed with style or template.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle PreviewMouseDown Event of the ScrollViewer.
In your xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <!--Button is removed as it will be not used-->
        <ScrollViewer Background="{x:Null}" Margin="20" PreviewMouseDown="ScrollViewer_MouseDown">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

As It is PreviewMouseDown (Tunneling) Event. So Wherever you click on scrollviewer, Event will be fired Whether it is Rectangle or ScrollViewer itself.

In your code behind, You can handle it by e.Source Parameter. 
PreviewMouseDown Event in .cs file is:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source.GetType() == typeof(ScrollViewer))
    { 
        //Code which you want to perform on that Button click will be here.
    }
    if (e.Source.GetType() == typeof(Rectangle))
    {                
        //Code which you want to perform on rectangle will be here.
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I understand you and thank you. It could work, but I have several complicated user controls on background with more mouse events. I think that it can work even in my case, but it will be very chaotic and not clean way.

Comment: @pav so can you  be more specific about your problem?

Comment: These rectangles are dialogs with chat and are visible (maximized) or collapse (minimalized, only names are visible) on the foreground. On the background is calendar with mouse events like google calendar. Number of chats is various and I use ScrollViewer for horizontaly scroll. Problem is, that if chats are visible, calendar is behind these chats and can not be clicked (or drag and drop). I read somewhere, that ScrollViewer can be without background (null), so it was my idea. Anyway if it is not posible, I must do it with canvas (without background) and two buttons like scroll.

Answer (score 0):

OK, You can use this example:

```
<Window x:Class="scrollviewerbackground.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:scrollviewerbackground"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="bt"></Button>
    <local:ScrollViewerClickable HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="20">
        <StackPanel IsHitTestVisible="True"  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{x:Null}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Margin="50"></Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </local:ScrollViewerClickable>
</Grid>
```

```
    public class ScrollViewerClickable : ScrollViewer
    {
        protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```